# Postgres password authentication fails

Tags: 13.10, postgresql

I've installed PostgreSQL 9.1 and pgadmin3 on Ubuntu Server 13.10.

I configured postgresql.conf with: `listen_addresses = '*'`

also I configured ph_hba.conf by changed peer connections to `md5`

Plus I reset the password of postgres by: `sudo password postgres`

then restarted the service with `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart`

after that I tried to connect to the default PostgreSQL template database:

```
sudo -u postgres psql template1
```

but login failed with this error message:

```
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

then I tried to login from the pgadmin, which gave me the same error.

I've read here that it might be a password expiry dates bug
[PostgreSQL user can not connect to server after changing password](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36137/postgresql-user-can-not-connect-to-server-after-changing-password)

but I couldn't solve it coz I cannot login with psql. Does anyone now how to resolve this issue?

**EDIT**

ph_hba file:

[here](http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/495051/pg-hba.html)

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I'm quite irritated by the fact that you have cloned this post. I just wrote an answer to this, only to discover that you also posted an identical question to stackoverflow.com that already had an accepted answer. **Don't copy and paste answers between sites, you're wasting everyone's time** and making it harder to find information. If you insist on doing this, make links between them.

Comment: SO link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21483540/398670

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You are confusing the password for the Unix user "postgres" with the database password for the database user "postgres". These are not the same.

You've locked yourself out, because you enabled `md5` authentication for database user `postgres` without setting a password for the database user `postgres`.

Add a new line to the top of `pg_hba.conf`:

```
local    postgres     postgres     peer
```

Then restart/reload PostgreSQL:

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql reload\
```

and run:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

From the resulting prompt:

```
ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'my_postgres_password';
```

remove the line you added to `pg_hba.conf` and restart Pg again. You can now use the password you set above to connect to PostgreSQL as the `postgres` user.

To learn more, read [the "client authentication" chapter of the user manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html) and [the docs on `pg_hba.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

Comment: Testing a new pg9.6.6  in a UBUNTU server 16 LTS.... And I was surprised by all these "beginner's problems". Arrive here with the solution... Do step by step ... The big surprise: not working!  `psql -W postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost` producing again same *"FATAL:  password authentication failed for user 'postgres'"*

Comment: Solution: all lines *trust* is working...

Comment: I am using ssh... After puting back all to md5, one by one (local, local, host...), only the line "host all 127.0.0.1/32 trust" can't change,  was preserved with "trust".  So, new question: why?

Comment: the `pg_hba.conf` file is owned by system user `postgres`. I only know the database password of database user `postgres`, So question is how do I edit this conf file without changing its ownership?

Comment: Can you tell please, what the line `local postgres postgres peer` really needed for in `pg_hba.conf`? Everything works well without it

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what my intuition telling me when I came to this problem...

Comment: Not working
db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "multibot_crm"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "multibot_crm"

Comment: @Craig Ringer ..Awesome. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Try to modify the password of the database template1 using this:

```
$ psql -c "ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'yourPassword'" -d template1
```

Comment: Gave me the same error but with user "root" instead of user "postgres"

Comment: Can you explain why this may help?

Answer (score 3):

in your pg_hba.conf

```
# IPv4 local connections:
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32         trust
```

if it does not work then try with

```
host    all         all         your_ip/32         trust
```

then restart your data base
it will work fine..
if you make trust then there is no need for password if you make MD5 then it will ask password...

Comment: do  not use this approach anywhere, you should always restrict user access to you data

Comment: unless you are running a CTF server.

Comment: where is `pg_hba.conf` file in ubuntu