# Postgres createdb is not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, postgresql

I have been trying for hours to create a database in a specific directory in Ubuntu 14.04.

First I tried

> ```
> createdb mydb
> ```

and I got

> ```
> createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  role "daniel" does not exist [daniel is my username]
> ```

Then I changed the password using

> ```
> sudo -u postgres psql
>
> \password postgres
> ```

and I tried

> createdb -U postgres -W  -E UTF-8 mydb

and I got

> ```
> createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
> ```

However, I am using the correct password. What must be happening?

By the way, I also tried the solution of [Postgress - Password autentication fails](https://askubuntu.com/questions/413585/postgres-password-authentication-fails?rq=1)

and I get

> ALTER ROLE

but the problem persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more hours, it seems I found the solution:

> sudo -u postgres psql
>
> CREATE ROLE username CREATEDB LOGIN PASSWORD 'password';

I basically created a user with privileges of database creation and login.