# Cannot get authorization to run pg_dumpall

Tags: bash, permissions, password, authentication, postgresql

All I am trying to do is backup my existing database cluster in order to upgrade from Postgresql 9.4.8 to 9.5. I am on Ubuntu 16.04.

I am aware of this post: [Postgres password authentication fails](https://askubuntu.com/questions/413585/postgres-password-authentication-fails). In fact, it was already bookmarked from the last time I had this problem. I do not claim any meaningful postgres knowledge. I don't always get what is supposed to be a psql command and what is supposed to be a bash command, and the blogs and what not I've seen don't always make that clear to me. PG is just my backend for my Django projects. I certainly don't understand how I am having this problem again.

My Ubuntu user is malikarumi. I have two postgres users, maikarumi and postgres. Postgres is the superuser. I tried to make malikarumi a superuser as well some time ago but that apparently failed and no, I don't know why.

Here is my first attempt today:

```
malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~$ pg_dumpall > 9-4-backup
pg_dumpall: query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for relation pg_authid
pg_dumpall: query was: SELECT oid, rolname, rolsuper, rolinherit,rolcreaterole, rolcreatedb, rolcanlogin, rolconnlimit, rolpassword, rolvaliduntil, rolreplication, pg_catalog.shobj_description(oid, 'pg_authid') as rolcomment, rolname = current_user AS is_current_user FROM pg_authid ORDER BY 2
```

This came next:

```
malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~$ pg_dumpall > 9-4-backup -U postgres
Password:
```

Note there nothing, no help, no indication what is wrong or what to do about it.

```
Password: 
Password: 
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "esselldb" failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
pg_dumpall: pg_dump failed on database "esselldb", exiting
```

Then I tried again with a blank password and a semicolon

```
malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~$ pg_dumpall > 9-4-backup -U postgres;
Password: 
pg_dumpall: could not connect to database "template1": fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Note the password works for psql

```
malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~$ psql -U postgres
Password for user postgres: Note the password works with psql
psql (9.4.8)
Type "help" for help.
```

But the command does not, with or without the semicolon

```
postgres=# pg_dumpall > 9-4-backup
postgres-# pg_dumpall > 9-4-backup;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "pg_dumpall"
LINE 1: pg_dumpall > 9-4-backup
```

This works

```
malikarumi@Tetuoan2:/etc/postgresql/9.4/main$ sudo cat pg_hba.conf
[sudo] password for malikarumi:
```

Apparently, this is the unix user, not the database user. But it is, and always has been, the same password.

I changed this

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                md5
```

to peer, as suggested in the prior post (again - how could it change back?!)

But I could not restart postgres

```
malikarumi@Tetuoan2:/etc/postgresql/9.4/main$ pg_ctl stop
pg_ctl: command not found
malikarumi@Tetuoan2:/etc/postgresql/9.4/main$ cd ~
malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~$ pg_ctl stop
pg_ctl: command not found
```

It did not work from psql either

```
postgres=# pg_ctl stop
postgres-# pg_ctl stop;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "pg_ctl"
LINE 1: pg_ctl stop
        ^
postgres=#
```

But at least psql still lets me in....

So I rebooted the whole machine and tried again. You know what happened

```
malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~$ pg_dumpall > 9-4-backup -U postgres
pg_dumpall: could not connect to database "template1": FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

So I did successfully change it, but I still can’t get it to work.  NOTE: It did NOT ask me for my password!

Then I tried this

```
malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~$ su postgres
Password: the right one
su: Authentication failure
malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~$ su postgres
Password: a blank one
su: Authentication failure
```

And now you are up to date. BTW, I have been to the official postgres docs many times, and find them dense and barely comprehensible. If you also know of a good base tutorial for a non db person like me, that would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All the mentioned failures are expected to happen, given the context, except that one:

```
malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~$ pg_dumpall > 9-4-backup -U postgres
Password:
```

Here you report a failure, but in the other situation below:

```
malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~$ psql -U postgres
Password for user postgres: Note the password works with psql
```

you report a success.

But that doesn't add up. The same password must work just as well for `pg_dumpall` in the precise context you mention, that is:

- the auth schema is set to `md5` in `pg_hba.conf` (before you change it in the rest of the post).
- the target database user is postgres through the `-U postgres` option.
- the command is called the shell from your own unix user `malikarumi`.

---

After you successfully change the auth scheme to `peer` (last part of your question), what goes wrong is that you try `su` instead of using `sudo`, the latter being the recommended method on Ubuntu.

Use this command at the shell prompt:

```
malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~$ sudo -u postgres pg_dumpall >9-4-backup
```

It will ask for a password, displaying something like:

```
[sudo] password for malikarumi:
```

Note that it expects **your password**, the same you use when opening your session under the `malikarumi` name, as opposed to the password of postgres, or a database password.

`sudo -u postgres somepostgrescommand` is just a variant of the `sudo someadmincommand` you're allowed to do if you're the admin of this Ubuntu workstation.